# How to Navigate from DRAWER NAVIGATION to BOTTOM TAB BAR NAVIGATION in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this url: https://streamable.com/no6anz, is a video showcasing my app's navigation, I want the ability to navigate from a Drawer screen to a ***SPECIFIC*** Tab Screen in my Tab Navigation.

For example: If i pressed let's say the 'Messages' drawer item, i would like to navigate to the *My Account* **tab** **screen** in the **tab navigator**.

So far my implementation has not been the best:

```
import React, {Fragment, Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Home from '../Views/HomeView';
import Cart from '../Views/CartView';
import MyAccount from '../Views/MyAccountView';
import Sidebar from '../Views/Sidebar';

import HomeIconColor from './CustomSVGIcons/HomeIconColor';
import CartIconColor from './CustomSVGIcons/CartIconColor';
import PersonIconColor from './CustomSVGIcons/PersonIconColor';
import MenuIconColor from './CustomSVGIcons/MenuIconColor';

import Contact from '../Views/screens/Contact';
import Messages from '../Views/screens/Messages';
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  DrawerActions,
  useNavigation,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {BottomTabBar} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Login from '../Views/screens/Login';
import {create} from 'react-test-renderer';
import {createSwitchNavigator} from '@react-navigation/compat';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Switch = createSwitchNavigator();

class Navigator extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MyDrawerNavigation />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
const MyTabs = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarButton: ['Contact', 'Route2ToExclude'].includes(route.name)
          ? () => {
              return null;
            }
          : undefined,
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="MyAccount"
        component={MyAccount}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={Cart}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Sidebar"
        component={Sidebar}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
const MyDrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerPosition={'right'}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={MyTabs}
        initialParams={{screen: 'Home'}}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="My Account"
        component={MyTabs}
        initialParams={{screen: 'MyAccount'}}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      tabNav: {
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
      },
    });

export default Navigator;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the screen as the initial param and it would redirect to the correct tab.

```
  <Drawer.Screen name="MyTabs" component={'Tab Component Name'} initialParams={{screen:'MyAccount'}}/>
```

Comment: Hey
Thanks for the swift response!

It HAS worked (using react navigation v5), thank you!!! :D

Comment: Hey Guruparan

Actually, it doesn't work... the app behaves weirdly and sometimes does not navigate to the specific tab ...

Comment: Yes I have updated the question; check the code for the updated MyDrawerNavigation =()=> 

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: here's a link showcasing the app behaving strangely at 1minute 30seconds https://streamable.com/p4vg18

Comment: I'm checking this

Comment: @bilaalsblog https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/tabnav it works, anything i'm missing here

Comment: Hey

Your example works because you only have one Drawer.screen with the initialParams props:

`      <Drawer.Screen
        name="MyTabs"
        component={MyTabs}
        initialParams={{ screen: 'Settings' }}
      />`

My code references two drawer.screen(s) with the initialParams props. Please check the video URL i have sent in my previous comment and you'll find that at 1minute 30seconds, when navigating between these two drawer screens (code snippet is above, in the question); sometimes the navigation does not navigate to the correct Tab.Screen.

Comment: OK i see that but why do you have multiple drawer screens? your code doesnt have that so hard for me to reproduce the issue

Comment: Hi,

Please refresh this post's webpage; you'll find that i've updated my code above. Please use the sample code above (in my initial post on this thread) as I've edited it.

You'll find two Drawer.Screen(s), both reference the initialParams property. initialParams={{screen: 'MyAccount'}} & initialParams={{screen: 'Home'}}.

Please check, thanks

Comment: I think its getting buggy as you keep switching to the same screen which is MyTabs with multiple params but the general way to go to a specific tab is to pass the screen parameter

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input

Though, when it gets buggy, if i save the file (Navigator.js), the app renders the correct screen instantaneously and the correct tab.screen shows.

Lol.... any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry i missed this, and good job on solving this yourself :)

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED!:

After extensively further researching; I have created my own custom Drawer, with the onPress handler.

The onPress handler initiates the action for navigation to the specified screens.

NOTE: you will have to pass in the navigation ref to the top-level navigation container. You will also have to pass this same reference into your custom drawer module (or any module in that concern)

here's my custom drawer component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {useNavigation, CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as rootNavigator from '../components/rootNavigator';

const CustomDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="My Account"
        onPress={() => rootNavigator.navigate('MyAccount')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Contact"
        onPress={() => rootNavigator.navigate('Contact')}
      />
      <Button title="Cart" onPress={() => rootNavigator.navigate('Cart')} />
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
  },
});
export default CustomDrawer;
```

here's the code where I return the DrawerNavBar:

```
const MyDrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerPosition={'right'}
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Tabs" component={MyTabs} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: In simple words, his question is how to synchron Drawer and Bottom Navigator, in his case if 'message' is clicked from Drawer then the 'message' on Bottom navigator is also focus or active. Your answer seem just to draw the navigation items inside drawer, not to synchron with Bottom navigator. Thanks