# Add Drawer on Tabs navigation with all tabs in drawer

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, drawer

I'm new to React native, Before duplicating i've tried various solutions such as
[How to Navigate from DRAWER NAVIGATION to BOTTOM TAB BAR NAVIGATION in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301678/how-to-navigate-from-drawer-navigation-to-bottom-tab-bar-navigation-in-react-nat) and
[Using DrawerNavigator alongside stack navigation on react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797258/using-drawernavigator-alongside-stack-navigation-on-react-native)
but none worked for my case.

What i want to achieve is, There are 2 screen stacks ie Login and Home screen.
I need the drawer only in home screen and not the login screen.
And in home screen there is a bottom tab navigator.
I want the drawer in home screen with all the tabs also when the screen in drawer is selected it should show the screen in bottom tab navigation.
Even a basic example will suffice.

Here's my code

```
const Tabs = () => {
return (
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
  }}
  barStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Trade"
    component={Trade}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon icon="eye" label="Trade" focused={focused} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="MyOrders"
    component={MyOrders}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon
          icon="shopping-bag"
          label="My Orders"
          focused={focused}
        />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Transport"
    component={Trade}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon icon="truck" label="Transport" focused={focused} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Transaction"
    component={Trade}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon icon="wallet" label="Transaction" focused={focused} />
      ),
    }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={Trade}
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
        <TabBarIcon icon="user" label="Profile" focused={focused} />
      ),
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
);
};

const DrawerStack = () => {
return (
<Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
  {/* <Drawer.Screen name="Trade" component={Trade}></Drawer.Screen>
  <Drawer.Screen name="MyOrders" component={MyOrders}></Drawer.Screen> */}
  <Drawer.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs}></Drawer.Screen>
</Drawer.Navigator>
);
};

const AppStack = () => {
return (
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="App" component={LoginStack}></Stack.Screen>
  <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={DrawerStack}></Stack.Screen>
</Stack.Navigator>
);
};

export default AppStack;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom drawer that focuses your bottom tab items which is registered inside your bottom tabs similar to the link in your question i.e. [How to Navigate from DRAWER NAVIGATION to BOTTOM TAB BAR NAVIGATION in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301678/how-to-navigate-from-drawer-navigation-to-bottom-tab-bar-navigation-in-react-nat)